# Can I add an existing java class to a sealed Kotlin class?

Tags: java, kotlin, sealed-class, kotlin-java-interop, kotlin-sealed

I am using 2 classes to handle error statuses, the Spring's own `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus` and my custom `ErrorStatus`:

```
enum class ErrorStatus(val code: Int, val reasonPhrase: String) {
    ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND(1404, "Element not found"),
    UNKNOWN_ERROR(1000, "Unknown Error"),
}
```

I would like to seal both classes using:

```
sealed interface Error
```

It's simple to do this with my class: `enum class ErrorStatus(val code: Int, val reasonPhrase: String) : Error {`

But is it possible to mark `HttpStatus` class as a part of this sealed interface?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot apply an interface to a class externally. Also, members of a sealed class or interface have to be defined inside the same project module as the sealed class or interface.

I would wrap the other class.

```
data class HttpStatusError(val status: HttpStatus): Error
```

You might consider making it an inline wrapper class:

```
@JvmInline value class HttpStatusError(val status: HttpStatus): Error
```